# 4TB Seagate Drive Freezes BIOS POST on Gigabyte Z77MX-D3H TH

Tags: hard-drive, bios, freeze

I recently bought a Seagate ST4000DM000 and installed it into my PC. The mobo is a Gigabyte Z77MX-D3H TH. The drive worked for a couple of days until I cleaned the inside of my PC and moved things around some.

Now, it no longer works. Worst of all, it freezes BIOS POST. It doesn't matter which SATA cable I use, or which SATA post I try, it freezes POST. Can't press DEL, or F9, or F12 or anything.

It doesn't matter if there are other drives or just the 4TB drive.

Here's the rub, if I leave the power cable plugged and enable SATA Hot swap, once the computer boots into the OS, I can plug the SATA cable into the drive and it pops up in the OS as an attached drive.

I tried putting the drive in another PC, it works fine.

I tried it in an external enclosure, it is detected fine (except since it's an old enclosure, it doesn't get more than 2TB).

On the Gigabyte MB, I first did a Bios recovery to the old F4. Then I updated to latest BIOS F7E. Reset CMOS, reset optimized defaults. Still nothing. The drive still freezes BIOS post.

Any ideas?

[HDTune Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL2N6.png)

Comment: I wonder if BIOS disabled SMART affects the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only case of drives freezing at POST I know of is because the BIOS firmware has bugs (assuming you ruled out a faulty drive). The background is that BIOS firmware tries to be smart and read partition tables on drives instead of just read the bootcode and boot right away. They analyse the partitioning in some cases to find special partitions containing extended functionality (restore partitions, extended service routines etc).

The firmware code that decodes partition tables is often a real mess and causes headaches to everyone, not just you. Some people installing alternative operating systems run into this problem and you hear them complain "xxx broke my PC, it does not boot anymore" and then they want their Windows back for which the mainboard manufacturers run the most/only tests for their firmware.

The solution is often to detach the drive and update/rollback the BIOS firmware. It is also possible to change the partitioning in a way that the firmware is happy with it, but it can take time to find out what the firmware chokes at. Then, you can also try to change the SATA port (many mainboards have got more than one controller, so maybe it triggers other kinds of behaviors).

Comment: Ok, so I should try rolling back to F4 bios? And I should try a different partition scheme on the drive? I don't mind loosing the data on it.

Comment: This is what I suggested, yes. Which way you want to solve it, depends on your preference. Of course you can also change the mainboard, if it annoying (btw, I actually like Gigabyte).

Comment: ya, Gigabyte is fine. However, I wish UEFI would die a horrible death.

Comment: OK, if the drive is FREE SPACE (ie No Partitions) it goes past POST.

Answer (score 3):

I chose Martin Sugioarto's answer since he recommended the file system might hang the BIOS.

This is the case.

The BIOS will not boot with an exFat partition larger than 2TB if this partition was created in Windows (ver 7) or Mac OS (ver 10.8.5).

If the exFat partition was created in Linux, it's ok if it is larger than 2TB. It boots fine with a 4TB exFat partition created in Linux.

I tried exFat partition in Windows both with 4Kb cluster size and 128Kb cluster size, no change. Won't boot.

I tried 1Tb + 3Tb (exFat) partitions in Mac OS. Won't boot.

I tried 2Tb + 2Tb (exFat) partitions in Mac OS. Boots Fine.

I tried 1Tb (HFS+ Journaled) + 3Tb (exFat). Won't boot. It seems any larger than 2Tb partition created in Windows or Mac will not boot past the Gigabyte BIOS.

SO, I will make the partition EXT4 and just use it this way and forgo exFat.

Answer (score -1):

That drive came out in 2013; but, at least its still in production....
Did you buy it new or used?
Either way, the thing to do is to check the drive's health and there is a relatively easy way to do it.  Go to http://www.hdtune.com/download.html and download hdtunepro_560_trial.exe which is free for 15 days.  I'd suggest you save it before you install it; but, either way, you need to install it and run it.
Select the drive from the drop down at the top and then look first on the Health tab.  The most important numbers are what is in the data (fourth) column for (05) Reallocated Sector Count and (C5)Current Pending Sector.  If either one of them is not zero, plain and simple, the drive is failing.  As long as it's there, you might want to look at (BF) G-sense Error Rate.  The number in the data (fourth) column is how many times the drive has detected excessive shocks.
Even if (05) and (C5) are zero, I would strongly suggest for you to go to the Error Scan tab and run it by clicking Start.  It may take hours if you have a one or two TeraByte drive; but, that is the surest test to verify the drive's operation.  If even one red box appears, you found the reason why your PC is freezing.

Comment: Well, it was brand new sealed. I checked it with SeaTools from seagate and it found no errors. Should I still use the HD Tune Pro?

Comment: I uploaded the result of HD Tune, I'm not sure I am reading correctly

Comment: The HDTune results aren't showing and I don't know how to help you upload a file or picture yet.  I'm new to this site; though, definitely not new to problems with hard disk drives.

Comment: It should just be a link to an imgur file: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VL2N6.png

Comment: The seek error rate in your image is a little alarming; but, its also a parameter I don't usually have to deal with.

Comment: Did you run the error scan?

Comment: I ran the quick version of the Error scan, did not want to wait for the slow one.

Comment: Only the non-Quick error scan is any good